# Avoiding NavigatorUserMediaError "Only secure origins are allowed" on HTTP in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, media

I'm trying to make some audio/video tests with a JavaScript library for SIP phones and since Chrome 47 I can no longer test in local development because of this error:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {}
constraintName: ""
message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see:https://goo. gl/Y0ZkNV)."
name: "PermissionDeniedError"
```

Is there an option (flag) in Chrome to disable this?
Or is there a way to download older versions of Chrome (I couldn't find any)?

Answer (score 7):

The *unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure* flag works for me as [documented here](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq).

On OS X this looks like:

```
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://alt.local:8080
```

For various reasons, my local development server doesn't run on **localhost** or port 80. Specifying the alternative port appears to be necessary.

The *user-data-dir* directive appears to create a temporary sandbox profile in Chrome.

Comment: Can I add an exception directly in the browser or config somewhere. Instead of running it like that.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features, localhost is supposed to be considered as a secure origin.

If you do not test on localhost but on a real domain, then you should enable an HTTPS access (you can get a free certificate with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/))