# Only secure origins are allowed

Tags: google-chrome, security, webcam

I have a server and machines that access my application with Google Chrone.

When trying to access the webcam I get this message:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed

I've found many solutions on stackoverflow for it, such as having SSL or executing chrome with options, but none of them seems to fit my need.

In my case I have a local network, and all machines access the "server" using its local IP: 192.168.0.100/myappWithWebCam

How could I guarantee a secure origin? The server is not published in the web. Is there a place on chrome where I can just "mark" this IP as secure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding NavigatorUserMediaError "Only secure origins are allowed" on HTTP in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463986/avoiding-navigatorusermediaerror-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-on-http-in-ch)

Comment: @Josh, I edited the question so you can understand why it is different from the other one.

Comment: It's really not a different question. The error message is clear, and the only secure origins are HTTPS and localhost, and it can be disabled on the command line. I don't know what the preferred solution is for 192.168.*, but you can imagine authorizing a LAN machine to access your laptop's  webcam and then getting pwned at a coffeeshop. Certificates and public keys solve this problem.